# Add column to file from another file where ID's match

Tags: unix, awk, cygwin, paste

I have a file like this:-

```
123,Bob
456,Joe
789,Jane
```

And a file like this

```
456,abc,Red
789,def,Yellow
```

I want to add column 3 from file 2 to file 1 but only where the first column matches, ending up with something like this:-

```
123,Bob
456,Joe,Red
789,Jane,Yellow
```

I have any tools available at the Cygwin commandline to do this, e.g. awk, paste etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have paste, you should also have join which is designed for this sort of thing. Assuming the input files are sorted on the key you can say:

```
join -t, in1 in2
```

Output:

```
456,Joe,Red
789,Jane,Yellow
```

#### Edit to accommodate new requirements

You can use the `-o` switch:

```
join -t, -o 1.1,1.2,2.3 in1 in2
```

You seem to want to keep unpaired lines from the first file, in that case use `-a1`:

```
join -t, -o 1.1,1.2,2.3 -a1 in1 in2
```

Output:

```
123,Bob,
456,Joe,Red
789,Jane,Yellow
```

This leaves an extraneous comma at the end of unpaired lines, but that can be removed with `| sed 's/,$//'`.

Comment: Nice. Edited question slightly, what if file2 has 3 columns, how do i just bring over column 3 ?